# How to disable notifications in Google Calendar entry and ignore defaults?

Tags: google-calendar

I want to keep my default notifications intact, but remove all notifications from some entries? Right now, even if I remove all notifications from a particular entry, the notification defaults are kicking in and still sending/showing notifications.

Is there a way to override the defaults by completely disabling them in particular entries?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to override the default notifications by changing the notifications for a specific event.

Here is a [link](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?hl=en) to Google Calendar notification options.